# Sending mail from Delphi using Thunderbird

Tags: delphi, email, thunderbird

I am in a situation where I need to send an email with attachments using Thunderbird and Delphi XE3
I have no idea as of where to start so I am asking if anyone has links to sites where I might find information.

Comment: Why do you need thunderbird? You can send the mails yourself using Indy SMTP.

Comment: That's tough. If Thunderbird is your default mail client you can ShellExecute an email address link, but that still leaves the attachments. Whosrdaddy's suggestion is better.

Comment: Thunderbird is MAPI compatible, so you can write a program that uses the default email client to send an email with attachments using MAPI, and if it is thunderbird (or other) it will work.  I found a simple example using google search for _delphi mapi_: http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/delphi/network/f236.shtml

Comment: try looking at MapiSendMail from unit Mapi; define the Thunderbird as default mail.

Comment: You asked for links. If you want to bypass Thunderbird, use Indy SMTP per whosrdaddy, try http://www.atozed.com/Indy/Demos/10/index.EN.aspx and download the "Send Mail" example at the bottom.

Comment: I don't need Thunderbird - the customer says 'I have Thunderbird, make your software use it' :-)
 As it is today I have SMTP via Indy and Outlook support.
 Maybe I should just add MAPI

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation, you can use Thunderbird's [command line options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Command_Line_Options), so I think using [ShellExecute](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/executeprogram.htm) should work. I have not tried this.

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'path\to\thunderbird.exe',
    '-compose "to=foo@nowhere.net,attachment=''file:///c:/test.txt''", 
    nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: If you execute the .exe directly then you should use `CreateProcess()` instead.  `ShellExecute()` simply delegates to `CreateProcess()` for .exe files, so you can cut out the middle man.

Comment: @RemyLebeau while it is true, CreateProcess is rather complex beast, price for its flexibility. So you'd better use some simplifying (dumbing-down) wrapper anyway. It can be Delphi wrapper like one in Jedi CodeLibrary, or you can use Microsoft-provided wrapper aka ShellExecute. If limited ShellExecute functionality is enough for you - why avoid using simple API ?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera - that might be an option. It looks like it is quite simple to ad this option then.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Noted, thank for your comment. Personally I don't do many system calls in my applications because I hate support (I make my .exe files as self-contained as possible.)

Comment: I have done some experiments with the command-line option and that does the trick 90%
The last 10% is that I need to require a read receipt and that doesn't look to be an option from command-line

Answer (score 2):

The following code is based on these two articles:

- [Dateien von der eigenen Anwendung per Drag and Drop zum Windows Explorer kopieren?](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/de/showcode.php?id=2335)
- [Programmatically use the SendTo mail recipient shortcut](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/sendtomail.aspx)

Steps:

Drop a FileListBox and a button on a form and set the FileListBox MultiSelect property to true.
Use this code to pass the selected entries in the filelistbox to the default mail application.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, FileCtrl;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    FileListBox1: TFileListBox;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  ActiveX, ShlObj, ComObj;

{$R *.dfm}

function GetFileListDataObject(const Directory: string; Files:
  TStrings):
  IDataObject;
type
  PArrayOfPItemIDList = ^TArrayOfPItemIDList;
  TArrayOfPItemIDList = array[0..0] of PItemIDList;
var
  Malloc: IMalloc;
  Root: IShellFolder;
  FolderPidl: PItemIDList;
  Folder: IShellFolder;
  p: PArrayOfPItemIDList;
  chEaten: ULONG;
  dwAttributes: ULONG;
  FileCount: Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if Files.Count = 0 then
    Exit;
  OleCheck(SHGetMalloc(Malloc));
  OleCheck(SHGetDesktopFolder(Root));
  OleCheck(Root.ParseDisplayName(0, nil,
    PWideChar(WideString(Directory)),
    chEaten, FolderPidl, dwAttributes));
  try
    OleCheck(Root.BindToObject(FolderPidl, nil, IShellFolder,
      Pointer(Folder)));
    FileCount := Files.Count;
    p := AllocMem(SizeOf(PItemIDList) * FileCount);
    try
      for i := 0 to FileCount - 1 do
      begin
        OleCheck(Folder.ParseDisplayName(0, nil,
          PWideChar(WideString(Files[i])), chEaten, p^[i],
          dwAttributes));
      end;
      OleCheck(Folder.GetUIObjectOf(0, FileCount, p^[0], IDataObject,
        nil,
        Pointer(Result)));
    finally
      for i := 0 to FileCount - 1 do
      begin
        if p^[i] &lt;&gt; nil then
          Malloc.Free(p^[i]);
      end;
      FreeMem(p);
    end;
  finally
    Malloc.Free(FolderPidl);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SelFileList: TStrings;
  I: Integer;
  DataObject: IDataObject;
  Effect: Integer;
  CLSID_SendMail: TGUID;
  DT: IDropTarget;
  P: TPoint;
begin
  CLSID_SendMail := StringToGUID('{9E56BE60-C50F-11CF-9A2C-00A0C90A90CE}');

  with FileListBox1 do
  begin
    SelFileList := TStringList.Create;
    try
      SelFileList.Capacity := SelCount;
      for i := 0 to FileListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
        if Selected[i] then
          SelFileList.Add(Items[i]);
      DataObject := GetFileListDataObject(Directory, SelFileList);
    finally
      SelFileList.Free;
    end;
    Effect := DROPEFFECT_NONE;
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SendMail, nil, CLSCTX_ALL, IDropTarget, DT);
    DT.DragEnter(DataObject, MK_LBUTTON, P, Effect);
    DT.Drop(DataObject, MK_LBUTTON, P, Effect);
  end;
end;

end.
```

(Tested with Delphi 2009)

---

My original blog article: http://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/how-can-i-simulate-send-to-with-delphi/